# Azure pipeline command line agent job seems to ignore the commands following the python environment activation?

Tags: python, windows, azure-pipelines, python-venv

I am using foll. code in azure pipeline command line agent job. But the commands after `Venv_Project\scripts\activate` do not show on the output. What could be the issue?

```
ECHO START
SET var=%cd%
ECHO %var%
python -m venv Venv_Project
SET var=%cd%
ECHO %var%
ECHO Venv created and now activating
Venv_Project\scripts\activate
SET var=%cd%
ECHO %var%
ECHO END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `Venv_Project\scripts\activate` with `call Venv_Project\scripts\activate`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#running-batch-and-cmd-files

> **Running batch and .CMD files**
>
> Azure Pipelines puts your inline script
>   contents into a temporary batch file (.cmd) in order to run it. When
>   you want to run a batch file from another batch file in Windows CMD,
>   you must use the call command, otherwise the first batch file is
>   terminated. This will result in Azure Pipelines running your intended
>   script up until the first batch file, then running the batch file,
>   then ending the step. Additional lines in the first script wouldn't be
>   run. You should always prepend call before executing a batch file in
>   an Azure Pipelines script step.
>
> Important
>
> You may not realize you're running a batch file. For example, npm on
>   Windows, along with any tools that you install using npm install -g,
>   are actually batch files. Always use call npm  to run NPM
>   commands in a Command Line task on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure pipeline command line agent job seems to ignore the commands following the python environment activation?

I could reproduce this issue on side. In order to further verify if the command was executed or not, or it executed but not display in the output.

I created a simple python script to create a `.txt` file, so we can verify that the command is executed by verifying the existence of the `.txt` file:

```
file = open('D:/a/1/s/Test.txt', 'w');
file.write('hello, \n world!')
```

When I build the command line task with private agent without python environment activation, it created the `.txt` file successfully. But if I activate the python environment activation, it will not create that file.

So, this further determines that the command is not being executed with Azure devops. But I have no way to further figure out the reason why Azure devops does not execute commands in the python virtual environment.

To resolve this issue, I would like suggest you report this issue on Developer Community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

which is our main forum for product issues. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.